# One word for "stand in good stead"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, idioms

The phrase is a bit of a cliché so I'm looking for something that doesn't sound so obvious.

> I have done xyz, which I believe will **stand me in good stead** for this job.

Can you provide another phrase meaning the same thing?

Comment: ***benefit*** :)

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage! Please **include the [research](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/5039/how-much-research-is-needed)** you've done.

Comment: * ... *position* me for this job"?

Comment: Thanks to the Simpsons, we now have *embiggens*. I wouldn't put it on my resume just yet, though.

Comment: ***serve me well***

Comment: @RichardKayser Position seems like the best option for my purposes. This ok? "I have done xyz, which I believe positions me well for this job."

Comment: @SayG Yep. Perfect.

Answer (score 1):

**"qualify"** is current usage and seems to fit.

"I have done xyz, which I believe **will qualify** me for this job.

> - [**qualify**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/qualifies) - "to provide or be provided with the abilities or attributes necessary for a task, office, duty, etc."

- His degree qualifies him for the job.
- He qualifies for the job, but would he do it well?.
- This specific training will qualify you to work as a plumber.
- Both candidates qualify for the job.
- Do they qualify to receive financial aid from the organization?
- The certification qualifies you to work in any state.

Comment: To me, "qualify" in this context suggests I'm competent but not at a clear advantage. 
I have done xyz, which I believe qualifies me for this job. 
Yes, but does it make you the front runner?

Comment: @SayG For a qualification to 'stand someone in good stead for a job' does not, to me, mean that the person is uniquely well qualified for the position, just that they are suitably qualified. If you want to convey this you could say something like 'makes me perfectly qualified' or 'is the best possible qualification' for the post.

Answer (score -2):

In this context "stand" and "stead" means different things serving different purposes for the subject.

Stand means place or put or portray. It's an action here.

Stead means advantage (place). It's a noun here

Advantage
Promote 
Recommend

Comment: This site strives to provide objective answers. As it stands your answer is purely subjective and could be improved by adding [references](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/59/77227). Take the [tour] or have a look at the [help] to find out more about good answers.

Comment: Stand in good stead is a common/lay term meaning that somebody or something is very apt for purpose. His or her use of the term is accurate, but then it's s/he is right to ask for an alternative.